# Find max of string column by length and assign to other rows of the same column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas column

| currency |
| --- |
| CNY |
| CNY,INR |
| INR |

after transform, the output should be

| currency |
| --- |
| CNY,INR |
| CNY,INR |
| CNY,INR |

Get the value by max of length and assign to the currency column

Answer (score 1):

Simple. use builtin `max` with `key=len`

```
df['currency'] = max(df['currency'], key=len)
```

---

```
  currency
0  CNY,INR
1  CNY,INR
2  CNY,INR
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the currency with maximum length:

```
currency_with_maximum_length = df.currency[df.currency.str.len().idxmax()] # 'CNY,INR'
```

And assign it to your column:

```
df['currency'] = currency_with_maximum_length
```

Output:

```
  currency
0  CNY,INR
1  CNY,INR
2  CNY,INR
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) combined with [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
df['currency'] = df.loc[df['currency'].str.len().idxmax(), 'currency']
```

output:

```
  currency
0  CNY,INR
1  CNY,INR
2  CNY,INR
```

This enables you to easily apply the same logic per group if needed:

```
g = df['currency'].str.len().groupby(df['group']).idxmax()
df['new_col'] = df['group'].map(g.map(df['currency']))
```

Example:

```
  group currency  new_col
0     A      CNY  CNY,INR
1     A  CNY,INR  CNY,INR
2     A      INR  CNY,INR
3     B      XYZ     WXYZ
4     B     WXYZ     WXYZ
5     B      INR     WXYZ
```